# Finding the most recent contract for each account

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to find the most recent entry for an account and only pulling that value for the account.  I am working with an oracle database. Here is an example:

```
account date    value
123456  4/20/2017   5
123456  1/20/2017   10
987654  2/5/2018    15
987654  12/31/2017  20
456789  4/27/2018   50
456789  1/24/2018   60
```

I would want to pull the 4/20/2017 value for 123456, the 2/5/2018 value for 987654, and the 4/27/2018 value for 456789.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT account, "date", "value"
FROM
(SELECT 
  account, "date", "value",
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY "date" DESC) rn
 FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn=1;
```

Note that the now deleted answer given by @NiVeR would suffice if we only wanted the max date for each account.  If we also need the value, or in general other columns from each record, then we would have to do an additional join, or use row number as I have done above.

See [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cbd1/2).

Comment: @cdaiga Thanks for the edit, though I don't know if we need to escape `date` and `value`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to Tim's answer, another option is to use an aggregate function with [`keep (dense_rank first ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238) or `last`:

```
select account, max(date_col) as max_date,
  max(value) keep (dense_rank last order by date_col) as value_from_max_date
from your_table
group by account;
```

which with your sample data supplied in a CTE (and changing the data column name to something valid) gives the same result:

```
with your_table (account, date_col, value) as (
            select 123456, date '2017-04-20', 5 from dual
  union all select 123456, date '2017-01-20', 10 from dual
  union all select 987654, date '2018-02-05', 15 from dual
  union all select 987654, date '2017-12-31', 20 from dual
  union all select 456789, date '2018-04-27', 50 from dual
  union all select 456789, date '2018-01-24', 60 from dual
)
select account, max(date_col) as max_date,
  max(value) keep (dense_rank last order by date_col) as value_from_max_date
from your_table
group by account;

   ACCOUNT MAX_DATE   VALUE_FROM_MAX_DATE
---------- ---------- -------------------
    123456 2017-04-20                   5
    456789 2018-04-27                  50
    987654 2018-02-05                  15
```

If you have a lot of columns to include from that target row then that gets messy and the other approach is simpler; but in some ways this is clearer for this situation (IMO).